# SQL select same column multiple times with different conditions

Tags: sql

I am trying to display several branches with their corresponding manager name, number of supervisors, and number of male and female staff. However the following error message pops up when I execute my query, "Column 'STAFF_T.stf_first_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." Please help me :)

```
SELECT  b.brc_id AS 'Branch ID',
        s.stf_first_name AS 'Manager First Name',
        s.stf_last_name AS 'Manager Last Name',
        (SELECT COUNT (sa.stf_position) FROM STAFF_T sa
         WHERE (sa.stf_position = 'Supervisor')) AS 'Number of Supervisor',
         (SELECT COUNT (sb.stf_position) FROM STAFF_T sb
          WHERE (sb.stf_position = 'Staff') AND
         (sb.stf_gender = 'Male')) AS 'Male Staff',
         (SELECT COUNT (sc.stf_position) FROM STAFF_T sc
          WHERE (sc.stf_position = 'Staff') AND
         (sc.stf_gender = 'Female')) AS 'Female Staff'
FROM BRANCH_T b, STAFF_T s
WHERE (b.brc_id = s.stf_brc_id) AND (b.brc_manager = s.stf_id)
GROUP BY b.brc_id
```

[This is my current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onLvB.png)
It is currently displaying the total number of supervisor, male staff, and female staff. It should display the amount of supervisor and staff based on each branch id.

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory. Which row of the group is it supposed to use for that value? When grouping, if it's not listed in the `GROUP BY`, a column can only be used with aggregate functions that act on the entire group.

Comment: Can you put a sample expected output?

Comment: The error says it all, you need to include columns **s.stf_first_name,s.stf_last_name** in the `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: Tried it already, still couldn't work >_<!!

Comment: @Unknown66 MJoy gave you the answer. If you tried it and it still didn't work, please edit your question to show the new code.

Comment: @Unknown66 please try if the query I posted works

Comment: @MJoy The query u posted worked, but the output wasn't display exactly as I wished.

Comment: @Unknown66 Perhaps you may have to use a `FULL OUTER/LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` - if that doesn't work, post some sample data with the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below query should work,

```
SELECT 
    b.brc_id AS [Branch ID]
    ,s.stf_first_name AS [Manager First Name]
    ,s.stf_last_name AS [Manager Last Name]
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN s.stf_position = 'Supervisor' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Number of Supervisor]
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN s.stf_position = 'Staff' AND s.stf_gender = 'Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Male Staff]
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN s.stf_position = 'Staff' AND s.stf_gender = 'Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Female Staff]
FROM BRANCH_T b
INNER JOIN STAFF_T s 
    ON b.brc_id = s.stf_brc_id AND b.brc_manager = s.stf_id
GROUP BY b.brc_id,s.stf_first_name,s.stf_last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing aggregate and non-aggregate queries, as the error message says. I'd query the branch table and join it twice - once on the staff table for the manager's details and once on an aggregate query from the staff table for the counts:

```
SELECT b.brc_id AS 'Branch ID',
       m.stf_first_name AS 'Manager First Name',
       m.stf_last_name AS 'Manager Last Name',
       c.supervisor_count,
       c.male_staff,
       c.female_staff
FROM   branch_t b
JOIN   staff_t m ON b.brc_manager = m.stf_id
JOIN   (SELECT     stf_brc_id, 
                   COUNT(CASE sa.stf_position WHEN 'Supervisor' THEN 1 END)
                         AS supervisor_count,
                   COUNT(CASE WHEN sb.stf_position = 'Staff' AND
                                   sb.stf_gender = 'Male' THEN 1 END) AS male_staff, 
                   COUNT(CASE WHEN sb.stf_position = 'Staff' AND
                                   sb.stf_gender = 'Female' THEN 1 END) AS female_staff
        FROM     staff
        GROUP BY stf_brc_id) c ON c.stf_brc_id = b.brc_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of RIGHT JOIN can make your query simple as below-

```
SELECT  S.stf_brc_id,
MAX(CASE WHEN B.brc_id IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE S.stf_first_name END) F_name,
MAX(CASE WHEN B.brc_id IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE S.stf_last_name END) L_name,
SUM(CASE WHEN S.stf_position = 'Supervisor' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 'Number of Supervisor',
SUM(CASE WHEN S.stf_position = 'Staff' AND S.stf_gender = 'Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 'Male Staff',
SUM(CASE WHEN S.stf_position = 'Staff' AND S.stf_gender = 'Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 'Female Staff'
FROM BRANCH_T B 
RIGHT JOIN STAFF_T S ON  B.brc_id = S.stf_brc_id AND B.brc_manager = S.stf_id
GROUP BY  S.stf_brc_id
```