# SQL Server : error "subquery returned more than 1 value"

Tags: sql-server, database, subquery

I have inserted a query to show the total number of supervisors, male and female staff in each branch of a company. However, there was an error in my query and I have no idea how to fix it... Please help me guys, thanks in advance.

```
SELECT  b.brc_id AS 'Branch ID',
        s.stf_first_name AS 'Manager First Name',
        s.stf_last_name AS 'Manager Last Name',
        (SELECT COUNT (sa.stf_position)
         FROM STAFF_T sa, BRANCH_T ba
         WHERE (sa.stf_position = 'Supervisor')
         GROUP BY ba.brc_id, sa.stf_first_name, sa.stf_last_name) AS  
'Number of Supervisor',
        (SELECT COUNT (sb.stf_position)
         FROM STAFF_T sb, BRANCH_T bb
         WHERE (sb.stf_position = 'Staff') AND (sb.stf_gender = 'Male')
         GROUP BY bb.brc_id, sb.stf_first_name, sb.stf_last_name) AS 'Male 
  Staff',
        (SELECT COUNT (sc.stf_position)
         FROM STAFF_T sc, BRANCH_T bc
         WHERE (sc.stf_position = 'Staff') AND (sc.stf_gender = 'Female')
         GROUP BY bc.brc_id, sc.stf_first_name, sc.stf_last_name) AS 
 'Female Staff'
 FROM 
     BRANCH_T b, STAFF_T s
 WHERE 
     (b.brc_id = s.stf_brc_id) AND (b.brc_manager = s.stf_id)
 GROUP BY 
     b.brc_id, s.stf_first_name, s.stf_last_name
```

The output should display total number of supervisors, male and female staff in each branch of the company. But the following error message pops up,

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 57
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: also should add your shema

Comment: I think it returns multiple records because it's grouped in a subquery.
Since they are already grouped in the main query, you'd be able to not have to use a subquery.

Comment: @mmukai But if I do so, the output will display the total number of supervisors, male staff and female staff of the entire database. I want it to display the numbers based on the Branch ID

Comment: You can specify the conditions by using a `CASE` clause.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56764963/sql-select-same-column-multiple-times-with-different-conditions
Here it seems to have got the answer, but something similar is also my opinion.
If the sample data and your expected results are not shown, it is difficult to answer although we can guess.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s That's actually an instruction given by my lecturer... He asked us to do the query using this way -_-!!

Comment: @Unknown66: then your lecturer urgently needs to update and refreshen his SQL skills!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your sub query is executed on the original tables, which has more than one tuple bc.brc_id, sc.stf_first_name, sc.stf_last_name. If you want to count on grouped data, use SUM CASE WHEN or SUM IIF like this:

```
SELECT  b.brc_id AS 'Branch ID',
        s.stf_first_name AS 'Manager First Name',
        s.stf_last_name AS 'Manager Last Name',
        SUM(IIF(s.stf_position = 'Supervisor', 1, 0)) AS 
'Number of Supervisor',
        SUM(IIF((s.stf_position = 'Staff') AND (s.stf_gender = 'Male'), 1, 0)) AS 'Male 
  Staff',
        SUM(IIF((s.stf_position = 'Staff') AND (s.stf_gender = 'Female'), 1, 0)) AS 'Female Staff'
 FROM 
     BRANCH_T b, STAFF_T s
 WHERE 
     (b.brc_id = s.stf_brc_id) AND (b.brc_manager = s.stf_id)
 GROUP BY 
     b.brc_id, s.stf_first_name, s.stf_last_name
```

And the second thing, the condition on where clause:

```
AND (b.brc_manager = s.stf_id)
```

seems to be wrong. With this condition, you only get the manager of each branch.  If you want to get the manager name, you must join to STAFF_T one more time. The final query should be:

```
SELECT  b.brc_id AS 'Branch ID',
        m.stf_first_name AS 'Manager First Name',
        m.stf_last_name AS 'Manager Last Name',
        SUM(IIF(s.stf_position = 'Supervisor', 1, 0)) AS 
'Number of Supervisor',
        SUM(IIF((s.stf_position = 'Staff') AND (s.stf_gender = 'Male'), 1, 0)) AS 'Male 
  Staff',
        SUM(IIF((s.stf_position = 'Staff') AND (s.stf_gender = 'Female'), 1, 0)) AS 'Female Staff'
 FROM 
     BRANCH_T b
     INNER JOIN STAFF_T s ON b.brc_id = s.stf_brc_id
     LEFT JOIN STAFF_T m ON b.brc_manager = m.stf_id
 GROUP BY 
     b.brc_id, m.stf_first_name, m.stf_last_name
```